# How to generate numbers of Observable under the given range and index inject into api with Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2

Given a `Observable<Resource>`with

`Resource` contains a property that `totalCount` and `name`,

then create a sequence such like that

`Single<Response> s1, Single<Response> s2, Single<Response> s3......till totalCount`

returned by the method called `Single<Response>  getResponse(String name, int index)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable<String> tableName = g.map(ExtraResource::getTableName);    
Observable<Integer> range = g.map(s -> s.getDataCount() % 100 + 1)
            .flatMap(v -> Observable.range(0, v));

Observable<Pair<String, Integer>> apiQuery
        = Observable.combineLatest(tableName, range, Pair::new);
```